# Magento2.3.1: How to Enable Flat Rate Shipping method on delivery not available products

Tags: shipping-methods, magento2.3.1, delivery

I have installed Check delivery available extension in my website.

Here the options are as follows:

1. Delivery available
2. Delivery Not Available.

For Available delivery, We added dummy pin codes. If any user checked delivery with non added pin codes, They will get display a message as **Delivery not available**.

I have enabled the flat rate option at shipping methods. And want to show for this non delivered products only.

Here, If any product is having the status **Delivery Not Available**, The shipping method should be Flat rate only.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Goto your shipping module to the model file like below:

> app/code/Vendor/StorePickup/Model/Carrier/StorePickup.php

There is a method name **collectRates**. You will find something like below code:

```
if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
    return false;
}
```

You can check your conditions, if you don't want to show the shipping method then return false else true like below:

```
// Checking if module is enabled or not.
if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
    return false;
}

// Your custom condition
if (IF SATISFY) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: see once. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281146/magento2-3-1-how-to-show-available-shiping-methods-based-on-product-delivery-av/281306?noredirect=1#comment402275_281306