# Magento 2.2.8 cannot find custom email template : Template file 'back_in_stock.html' is not found

Tags: magento2.2, email, email-templates

I'm creating an extension which sends email from command console and / or cron.

https://github.com/DominicWatts/BackInStock/tree/develop

In https://github.com/DominicWatts/BackInStock/blob/develop/Helper/Data.php#L168-L226

I've got this

```
const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'backinstock/email/template';

    public function sendTransactionalEmail($vars = [])
    {
        $email = $vars['email'] ?? null;
        if (empty($vars) || !$email) {
            return;
        }
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        try {
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($vars);

            $recipient = [
                'firstname' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml($vars['firstname']),
                'email' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml($vars['email']),
            ];

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

            $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(
                $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                    self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
                    $storeScope
                )
            )->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                ]
            )->setTemplateVars(
                [
                    'firstname' => $vars['firstname'] ?? null,
                    'lastname' => $vars['lastname'] ?? null,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'productname' => $vars['productname'] ?? null,
                    'productlink' => $vars['productlink'] ?? null
                ]
            )->setFrom(
                $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                    self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
                    $storeScope
                )
            )->addTo(
                $recipient['email'],
                $recipient['firstname']
            );

            $transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

            return true;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

https://github.com/DominicWatts/BackInStock/blob/develop/etc/email_templates.xml

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="backinstock_email_template" label="Back In Stock" file="back_in_stock.html" type="html" module="Xigne_BackInStock" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

Email template is in place

https://github.com/DominicWatts/BackInStock/blob/develop/view/frontend/email/back_in_stock.html

Then with some dummy data in I try and run

`php bin/magento xigen:backinstock:check check`

```
2019-07-08 23:15:04 Start Notification Process


  [UnexpectedValueException]                        
  Template file 'back_in_stock.html' is not found.  


xigen:backinstock:check <check>
```

So that says to me my XML and logic is correct.

Magento is just not seeing my email template.  Trouble is I just can't see what's wrong. Path looks correct.

Tried clearing cache, di compile, setup upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was a typo in email_templates.xml

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="backinstock_email_template" label="Back In Stock" file="back_in_stock.html" type="html" module="Xigen_BackInStock" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

`module="Xigen_BackInStock"` part was incorrect.  So all values being pulled through were correct and files were in the right place.  That was enough to make magento not look in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

Change following code:

```
'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
```

**DEFAULT_STORE_ID** is 0 which is for admin. Assing valid store id instead of 0. Ex:

```
'store' => 1
```

OR

Transfer your template to **view/base/email** folder.

Comment: Hi please help me on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281146/magento2-3-1-how-to-show-available-shiping-methods-based-on-product-delivery-av?noredirect=1#comment402209_281146

Comment: Thanks. I rewrote it slightly. I now store store ID in db to cope with multisite scenario but still getting same error. Its bizarre. https://github.com/DominicWatts/BackInStock/blob/master/Helper/Data.php#L198 also tried template in base.  I'm going to try a cpanel server tomorrow. Maybe something wrong with my dev.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this way,**

Get Store id like this, add this class in your `__construct()`

> Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface

`'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());`

```
$transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(
                $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                    self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
                    $storeScope
                )
            )->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                    'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
                ]
            )->setTemplateVars(
                [
                    'firstname' => $vars['firstname'] ?? null,
                    'lastname' => $vars['lastname'] ?? null,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'productname' => $vars['productname'] ?? null,
                    'productlink' => $vars['productlink'] ?? null
                ]
            )->setFrom(
                $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                    self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY,
                    $storeScope
                )
            )->addTo(
                $recipient['email'],
                $recipient['firstname']
            )->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
```

Comment: Thanks. I rewrote it slightly. I now store store ID in db to cope with multisite scenario but still getting same error. Its bizarre.  https://github.com/DominicWatts/BackInStock/blob/master/Helper/Data.php#L198 I'm going to try a cpanel server tomorrow. Maybe something wrong with my dev.

Comment: @DominicXigen there is no `system.xml` file in provided link, how did you get the path for `XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE`?

Comment: I define a default https://github.com/DominicWatts/BackInStock/blob/master/etc/config.xml as pulled 'back_in_stock.html' value I assumed this would be enough.  This comes from https://github.com/DominicWatts/BackInStock/blob/master/etc/email_templates.xml

Comment: can you tell where is this in default configuration?